# Analyze exam result limitation (Java)

Tags: java

I'm Beginner and i'm doing the exercise from Deitel How to program i make the program that analyze the exam result and output that the bonus give to the instructor or not. my program works fine but i want that if user inputs the value other than 1 or 2 then it should give an error and terminates the program.

```
Following is the code:

    package test;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class apple {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      int failure = 0;
      int passes = 0;
      int counter = 1;
      while (counter <= 10){
          System.out.print("Enter Result (For Pass Enter 1 or for Fail Enter 2): ");
          int result = input.nextInt();
          if (result == 1)
              passes = passes + 1;
          else 
              failure = failure + 1;
          counter = counter + 1;

      }
      System.out.printf("Total Pass Students are %d and Failed are %d" ,passes , failure );`enter code here`
      if (passes > 8)
          System.out.println("\nBonus to instructor");
        }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about throwing an Exception for other number? You should probably use your own not general Exception so please replace it by suitable class extending Exception.

```
      if (result == 1)
          passes = passes + 1;
      else if (result == 2)
          failure = failure + 1;
      else
          throw new Exception("Wrong value");
```